# Reading multiple text files with different names in java

Tags: java, file, io, text-files

I have this problem where I have 20 text files with almost the same name but different text in them (it has int&double values inside).Thier names are like this:

- fake_weather_riyadh_1
- fake_weather_riyadh_2
- fake_weather_riyadh_3

etc. Until it reaches 20

so my problem is which method do I need to use in order to make the program read 
all of the contents of these files without having to write:

```
String inputFileName = "fake_weather_riyadh_1.txt";
String inputFileName = "fake_weather_riyadh_2.txt";
```

etc.

Note: I'm still kind of a beginner in Java.

I hope I was clear and Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: @John Take a look at my solution, if you have more doubts, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put all those files in a directory and then list the directory content, like this:

```
File directory = new File("directory/path");
File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    // Access file.getName() or do anything else here
}
```

Or if you just know the filenames in advance and want to read only those specific files, assuming they are numbered like in your question, you use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    String filename = "fake_weather_riyadh_" + i + ".txt"
    // Read file content here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to put these files into a specific directory. Then you can list the files via fs operations and store them in an array. After that you can iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
//Scan through the files in the directory

if (filename.startsWith("fake_weather_riyadh"))  //where filename is a String
    //read this file
```

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your effort